# when eject ios get error ld: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'

Tags: react-native, expo

when i eject from expo with this command line expo run:ios , give me this error after install pod dependency

[screen shot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsLaa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Link your native dependencies: `npx react-native link`

All libraries with native dependencies should be successfully linked to your iOS/Android project.

or, Try linking them manually. `react-native link <Package-Name>`

Read docs [Linking Libraries](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios)